# pass the data of a specific key from javascript to vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vue, have a web app.
In the javascript, there queryset data, which contains key like title, author, etc.
I want to pass the value corresponding to title key to vue.
How could I do this?

I have tried book.title, but got error in vue.

```
            <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index) in filteredRows" :key="`iSBN-${index}`">
            <td v-html="highlightMatches(row.title)">{{ row.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.author }}</td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

                <script>
        var book = {{ query_results_book_json|safe}};
        console.log(book);
        const app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                filter:'',
                rows: [
                    { title: book.title, author: '' }
                ]
            }
})
</script>
```

Comment: If you got an error. What was the error then?

Comment: Not possible. You can pass only component to component

Comment: @Mr. Perfectionist   Then how could I get book.title in vue?

Comment: @BadPiggie    vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The `data` property must be a function.

```js
const book = {title: 'Some Title', author: 'Some Author'};

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    filter: '',
    rows: [book]
  }),
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.rows);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: title is not const in my case, it's from a json data (query_results_book_json) rendered from backend

Comment: Can you post your full code in a snippet?

Comment: updated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251127/get-the-value-of-a-specific-key-from-django-queryset-json-data-and-pass-to-javas